# Returning another value if preferred value is null

Tags: sql

SQL noob here struggling with a query...

I have two tables, one that contains product information (ItemCode, ItemName) and one that contains different price lists (up to 10) for each product.

In plain English, this is what I want to achieve:

```
Select T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName, T1.Price
```

Take the price from price list 6: if price in price list 6 is null, then take the price from price list 1 and deduct 5%

It seems like it should be fairly straight forward but I'm not really sure where to begin to be honest I'd be grateful for some advice.

Many thanks,
Michael

Comment: Show some table data if possible please.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing this with two joins, one for each price list:

```
 select pi.ItemCode, pi.ItemName,
        coalesce(pl6.price, pl1.price*0.95) as price
 from ProductInformation pi left outer join
      PriceList pl6
      on pi.ItemCode = pl6.ItemCode and pi6.List = 6 left outer join
      PriceList pl1
      on pi.ItemCode = pl1.ItemCode and pi1.list = 1;
```

This assumes that the price lists are on different rows.  If they are on the same row (`price1`, `price2` . . .), then this will work:

```
 select pi.ItemCode, pi.ItemName,
        coalesce(pl.price6, pl.price1*0.95) as price
 from ProductInformation pi left outer join
      PriceList pl
      on pi.ItemCode = pl.ItemCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `coalesce` function which looks like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.PRICE,"MISSING") FROM [TABLE]
```

You can find more information on it in your RDBMS' documentation but this will return "missing" if the field returns a NULL.